# Views and copies confusion with NumPy arrays when combining index operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, copy

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

>>> a[0:3:2, :][:, [0,2]] = 100   ### the first time
>>> a  
array([[100, 1, 100, 3],
[ 4, 5, 6, 7],
[100, 9, 100, 11]])

>>> a[:, [0, 2]][0:3:2, :] = 0    ### second time
>>> a   
array([[100, 1, 100, 3],
       [ 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [100, 9, 100, 11]])
```

I am really confused about views and copies in python. The code above shows that the first time the given rows and columns in array a was changed to 100, which changed the original array a.

However, the second time the original array was not changed. Why is that?

Comment: Indexing with one set of [] is usually better: `a[0:3:2, [0,2]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **lookup** with `[:, [0,2]]` will return a copy because it's [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). However when you **assign to a slice** (e.g. `array[whatever] = sth`) it won't create the copy but assign to the specified items, even if it's advanced indexing.

So the first example works because the first slicing returns a view and then it uses assignment for the slice of the view.

However the second one "fails" because you assign to a slice of a copy (because the advanced indexing is done **before** the regular indexing).

The difference is mainly because another method is responsible for setting ([`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__)) to slices than for getting ([`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)) these slices. To disassemble your statements:

```
a[0:3:2, :][:, [0,2]] = 100 

a.__getitem__((slice(0, 3, 2), slice(None))).__setitem__((slice(None), [0, 2]), 100)
|-------------- returns a view ------------|
```

while the second one would be:

```
a[:, [0,2]][0:3:2, :] = 0

a.__getitem__((slice(None), [0, 2])).__setitem__((slice(0, 3, 2), slice(None)), 0)
|--------- returns a copy ---------|
```

Comment: I looked up the link to advanced indexing that you provided above but I am still not sure what's the difference between '[0:3:2, :]' and '[:, [0,2]]'. For me, both look like a tuple and why one is advanced indexing and the other one is regular indexing?

Comment: @BrattSwan The `[0, 2]` for the second axis is interpreted as "integer array" which makes NumPy use integer array indexing (which returns a copy). However the `0:3:2` is a normal `slice` so NumPy uses basic slicing (which returns a view).

Comment: Really? What you get depends on how you index it? This is crazy! Is there a way to force it to return only a view / copy? Thanks

Comment: @Confounded It's not crazy - it's completely deterministic when you get a view (basic indexing) and when you get a copy (advanced indexing). So if you always want a copy then just make a `.copy()` on the return of the basic-indexing. But if you cannot use basic slicing then there's no way to get a view by indexing so you can't "always return a view".

Comment: It is crazy because you have to worry about index design. Why can't advance indexing return pointers to the appropriate positions of the base array?

Comment: @Confounded Yes you have to worry about index design. But that's why there's also [extensive documentation about it](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). If you get familiar with NumPy this will become easier. With regards to your second question: NumPy arrays are [strided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array) that means only certain memory-patterns are possible (offsets/steps in each dimension). If it weren't strided it would be much bigger (memory-wise - thus not really taking advantage of having views) and a lot slower.

Comment: Extensive documentation? Language should be intuitive, not require reading extensive documentation. I think it's poor design. Also, a default behavior should always be a copy, and if one needs a view it should be requested explicitly. Again, bad design in my view.

Comment: On the strided property. It's still not clear to me why an object created with advance indexing cannot contain pointers to the base array. How does this strided property prevent us from storing them?

Comment: @Confounded If you want to argue about design decisions you should probably go to the NumPy mailing list, the comments on stack-overflow aren't a good place for it. Also I've been using NumPy for so long that I'm too familiar with it and likely biased.

Comment: @Confounded Strided means that an array is represented by a base-memory-address and strides (steps for each dimension). That means you can access an element by using `base-memory-address + (dimension1 * stride1 + dimension2 * stride2 ...)`. With basic slicing you can simply return an array with shifted base-memory address and changed strides. With advanced indexing you get arbitrary elements from the array, so cannot use modified strides because you could have overlapping or non-contiguous steps. So the only (consistent) way you can implement advanced indexing is: creating a new array + copy.