# Cannot draw a line in image without creating it's copy.(Issue exist in only .png images)

Tags: python, opencv

Below code doesn't draw any line on png image

```
imgPath = "./images/dummy.png"

img = cv2.imread(imgPath,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) 
imgBGR = img[:,:,:3] 
imgMask = img[:,:,3]

cv2.line(imgBGR, (200,100), (250,100), (0,100,255), thickness=9, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
plt.imshow(imgBGR[:,:,::-1])
```

On creating copy of BGR channel and using it to draw line works.

```
imgPath = "./images/dummy.png"

img = cv2.imread(imgPath,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) 
imgBGR = img[:,:,:3] 
imgMask = img[:,:,3]

imgBGRCopy = imgBGR.copy()

cv2.line(imgBGRCopy , (200,100), (250,100), (0,100,255), thickness=9, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
plt.imshow(imgBGRCopy [:,:,::-1])
```

Please explain why?

Comment: Have a read about copies and views... https://www.jessicayung.com/numpy-views-vs-copies-avoiding-costly-mistakes/

Comment: @MarkSetchell I do understand that **imgBGR** is a view of **img**.

Comment: Does `img.shape` end in `4` and your PNG has an alpha channel whereas a JPEG doesn't?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, my png image is having 4 channels(including alpha). First code works with JPEG image after commenting **imgMask = img[:,:,3]** line as it is having only 3 channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mysterious reason OpenCV fails for draw on a NumPy slice.

See the following post for example: [Why cv2.line can't draw on 1 channel numpy array slice inplace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540401/why-cv2-line-cant-draw-on-1-channel-numpy-array-slice-inplace)

The error is not related to PNG vs JPEG, or to BGR vs BGRA.
The error is because you are trying to draw on a slice.

For example, the following code also fails:

```
imgBGR = cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
imgB = imgBGR[:,:,0]  # Get a slice of imgBGR
cv2.circle(imgB, (100, 100), 10, 5)
```

As an alternative, you can draw on the BGRA image.

According to [Drawing Functions](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html) documentation:

> **Note** The functions do not support alpha-transparency when the target image is 4-channel. In this case, the color[3] is simply copied to the repainted pixels. Thus, if you want to paint semi-transparent shapes, you can paint them in a separate buffer and then blend it with the main image.

The following code is working:

```
img = cv2.imread(imgPath,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) 
cv2.line(img, (200,100), (250,100), (0,100,255), thickness=9, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

imgBGR = img[:,:,:3] 
plt.imshow(imgBGR[:,:,::-1])
```

---

Note:
Python an OpenCV are "Open Source", so in theory we can follow the source code and demystify the problem.