# Changing values in Numpy array according to index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I use the indices once to change the values, it works.
However, when I use the indices twice to change the values, nothing has changed.
Why I can't use the indices twice to change the values?

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(100)
a[np.array([10,20,30,40,50])] = 1

print(a[np.array([10,20,30,40,50])])

# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) which can be modified as 1

a = np.arange(100)
(a[np.array([10,20,30,40,50])])[np.array([1,2,3])] = 1

print((a[np.array([10,20,30,40,50])])[np.array([1,2,3])])

# array([20, 30, 40]) which can not be modified as 1
```

Comment: `(a[np.array([10,20,30,40,50])])` makes a new, not a `view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confusing question about views and copies in NumPy.
I found this question [[Numpy: views vs copy by slicing]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181092/numpy-views-vs-copy-by-slicing) is similar to this one and this doc [[Views versus copies in NumPy]](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html) mentioned by @Maltimore may explain.

**NumPy Fancy Indexing returns a copy of numpy array instead of a view.**
However, when set values to numpy array using fancy indexing, what python interpreter does is calling `__setitem__` function. Take the code as an example.

In this line:

```py
a[np.array([10,20,30,40,50])] = 1
```

What python actually does is

```py
a.__setitem__(np.array([10,20,30,40,50]), 1)
```

> i.e. there is not need to create neither a view or a copy because the method can be evaluated inplace (i.e. no new object creation is involved).

Break this line into the following code:

```py
# (a[np.array([10,20,30,40,50])])[np.array([1,2,3])] = 1
a_copy = a[np.array([10,20,30,40,50])]
a_copy[np.array([1,2,3])] = 1

print(a[np.array([10,20,30,40,50])])
# [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

print(a_copy)
# [10,  1,  1,  1, 50]
```

As a result, this line modifies the value of the copy, so the original numpy array is unchanged.