# Numpy Advanced Indexing confusion

Tags: numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array, indexing, numpy-ndarray

If a is numpy array of shape (5,3), b is of shape (2,2) and c is of shape (2,2), what is the shape of a[b,c]?

Can anyone explain this to me with an example. I've read the docs but still I am not able to understand how it works.

Comment: What are the contents of `b` and `c`? It should contain valid indices for `a[b, c]` to work without any errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the purpose of expounding the concept of advanced indexing, here is a contrived example:

```
# input arrays
In [22]: a
Out[22]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])

In [23]: b
Out[23]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])

In [24]: c
Out[24]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 2]])

# advanced indexing
In [25]: a[b, c]
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0,  4],
       [ 8, 11]])
```

By the expression `a[b, c]`, we are using the arrays `b` and `c` to selectively pull out elements from the array `a`.

To interpret the output of `a[b, c]`:

```
    # b            # c            # 2D indices
    [[0, 1],       [[0, 1]   ---> (0,0)  (1,1)
     [2, 3]]        [2, 2]]  ---> (2,2)  (3,2)
```

The 2D indices would simply be applied to the array `a` and the corresponding elements would be returned as array in the result of `a[b, c]`

```
 a[(0,0)]  --> 0
 a[(1,1)]  --> 4
 a[(2,2)]  --> 8
 a[(3,2)]  --> 11
```

The above elements are returned as a 2D array since the arrays `b` and `c` are 2D arrays themselves.

---

Also, please note that advanced indexing always returns a copy.

```
In [27]: (a[b, c]).flags.owndata
Out[27]: True
```

However, an *assignment* operation using *advanced* indexing will alter the original array (in-place). But, this behaviour is also dependent on two factors:

- whether your indexing operation is pure (only *advanced* indexing) or mixed (a combination of *advanced & simple* indexing)
- in case of mixed indexing, the order in which they are applied.

---

See: [Views and copies confusion with NumPy arrays when combining index operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308370/views-and-copies-confusion-with-numpy-arrays-when-combining-index-operations)

Comment: I think your last point is wrong. I did try `a[b,c] = -1`, and this changes `a`. You need to update your answer.

Comment: Try this minimum example:
```python
x = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)
print("x =\n", x)
row = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
col = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 2]])
print("row =\n", row)
print("col =\n", col)
ind = tuple([row, col])
print("x[ind] = -1")
x[ind] = -1
print("x =\n", x, end="\n\n\n")
```

Comment: This feature will be useless if one cannot in-place change the elements carefully selected.

Comment: @Rainning thanks! My answer was correct. I just didn't add enough details to clarify views vs. copy scenario in case of an assignment op., which I've done now. Please see the updated answer.